# Latitude and Longitude of US Commuting Zones

Tags: data.gov

Is there any dataset containing the latitude and longitude of US commuting zones? (e.g. an Excel sheet containing the coordinates of Minneapolis-St. Paul, etc.)

Comment: Do you mean metropolitan areas?

Answer (score 2):

You can find out information about Americans' commuting habits in relation to specific geographic areas through the U.S. Census American Community Survey.  Access to the data is [available](http://www.census.gov/acs/www/data_documentation/data_main/).  For example, if you are looking for how people in [Los Angeles County get to work](http://www.census.gov/acs/www/data_documentation/data_easy_stats/), you can find the answer through the Easy Stats online.

[image: L.A. County Transportation Choices]

The longitude and latitude of all U.S. boundaries (from school districts to counties to roads) can be found via [TIGER files](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger.html) (topographically integrated geographic encoding and referencing).